# Nothing will load on the password recovery link

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forgot-password

I have created a password recovery function for the user. So when the user goes in to the normal website www.foobar.com/passwordRecovery , the user can request a new link to change it's password. The user will then recieve an email in with a link that is crypted and will look something like this www.foobar.com/passwordRecovery/crypted msg/. The problem is when the user clicks this link none of the javascript or css is loaded. its only html. Why is it like this? I get error code in the consol that says

> stylesheet http://localhost/password_retrival/passwordRetrival.inc.php/jquery-ui-1.11./jquery-ui.css loaded as CSS even if its MIME-typ, ”text/html”, is not ”text/css”.
>
> Expecting a selector . Rule Set ignored due . invalid selector
>
> The stylesheet http : //localhost/password_retrival/passwordRetrival.inc.php/passwordRetrivalStyle.css loaded as CSS even though its MIME type , " text / html " , is not " text / css " .

Comment: Please show the code of the failing html/php page to help the php guru's looking for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your css in your HTML like this:

```
<link href="http://localhost/password_retrival/passwordRetrival.inc.php/jquery-ui-1.11./jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks , but now it will load everything two times

Comment: Can you post your <head>  tag (or the part of code, where css and js is defined)?

Comment: Nvm i just realized i imported the url twice in smarty mb! Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah sorry i m new to this site , is it accepted now ? :)